# pandas shift column for customer last purchase

Tags: python, pandas

I want to use pandas shift function to group by and then ungroup.

**original table**

```
 customer_id | date | price
a | 4/11/2022 | 10 
b | 5/11/2022 | 20 
c | 5/11/2022 | 30 
a | 6/11/2022 | 20
b | 6/11/2022 | 20
a | 7/11/2022 | 30
```

**target**

```
customer_id | date | price | last_purchase
a | 4/11/2022 | 10 | NaN
b | 5/11/2022 | 20 | NaN
c | 5/11/2022 | 30 | NaN
a | 6/11/2022 | 20| 10
b | 6/11/2022 | 20 | 20 
a | 7/11/2022 | 30| 20
```

I can do it with the group_by function and then do a join to original table, but i feel that there is a better and cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
df['last_purchase'] = df.groupby('customer_id')['price'].shift(1)
```

Comment: I knew it was simple, thank you very much